# Read in multiple CSV file paths on R script HDFS file system object

Tags: r, hdfs, azure-blob-storage

I have around 10K files in the azure Blob. Using the HDInsight I created a cluster and now I am running an R script on the R server. Here's the code so far, but now I' am clueless about reading in mulitple *.csv files from the Azure blob storage. From the code, bigDataDirRoot has all the csv files. Any help will be greatly apprecaited.

```
myNameNode<-"wasb://zodiaclatency@audiencemeasurement.blob.core.windows.net"
myPort<-0
bigDataDirRoot<-"/zodiac_late_events_files_upload"

#Define Spark compute Context: to distribute computation onSpark Cluster
mySparkCluster<-RxSpark(consoleOutput = TRUE, nameNode = myNameNode, port = myPort)

#set compute context
rxSetComputeContext(mySparkCluster)

# HDFS file system object generator:
hdfsFS <- RxHdfsFileSystem(hostName=myNameNode, port=myPort)
```